# Does Django development follow the Bazaar Model of development?

Tags: django, open-source, coding-style, bazaar

Some would argue that [Bazaar Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cathedral_and_the_Bazaar) of development can lead to a tangled mess of [cowboy code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_coding).

I'm wondering, which model does Django follow?  At first glance it seems to be a highly organized bazaar model, with vetting and triage stages and such.  However, the source *is* available at all times, but not every patch or suggestion gets randomly added to the code base.  Likewise, major versions (0.96, 1.0, 1.0.2, 1.1, etc.) are somewhat cathedral in their presentation.

Which is it and why?

Comment: "Some would argue that Bazaar Model of development can lead to a tangled mess of cowboy code."

I've never heard anyone make a claim as silly as this.

Comment: To clarify, Bazaar without very good management can lead to poor trunk code.

Comment: I think you need to define your terms.  You seem to be using a definition of "Bazaar model" which doesn't match anything I've ever heard of ("every patch or suggestion gets randomly added to the code base"???).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 2):

It's an open-source project, so could be described as following the Bazaar model. However I think this question is rooted in a misunderstanding of what that is.

There's nothing in that model to insist that any random rubbish gets committed to the code. I've never heard of an open-source project where that was the case (maybe because anything that did follow that would indeed be a tangled mess, and unlikely to be successful).

And again there's nothing in that model to say you can't have major version numbers. These are just a snapshot of the code at that point. You can download and deploy the code as it was one commit before or after version 1.0.2, with nothing to stop you.